# Matlab function takes 1 argument, Java caller provides 2

Tags: matlab-deployment

The Mathworks page for an example [makesqr.m](https://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/gs/create-a-java-application-with-matlab-code.html) shows a 1-argument function:

```
% makesqr.m
%----------
function y = makesqr(x)
y = magic(x);
```

This gets generated into a Java package.  However, the `step 16` of the [Java invoker](https://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/java/integrating-a-java-class-into-an-application.html) shows `makesqr` with *two* arguments:

```
result = theMagic.makesqr(1, n);
```

Can anyone please explain this difference in the number of arguments?

Answer (score 1):

The extra leading argument specifies the number of output arguments that Matlab should return to the Java invoker. The page [Pass Arguments To and From Java](https://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/java/passing-arguments-to-and-from-java.html) describes this and how multiple inputs/outputs are accomplished.